# GDAL warping with shift vectors

Tags: python, gdal

Is there a way to warp image using shift vectors with GDAL (with Python API)?

By shift vectors, I mean eg. CSV (or numpy) file with following columns: `starting_x,starting_y,target_x,target_y`. The image is eg. a Tiff (or GeoTiff) file.

I did not find anything like supporting multiple shift vectors in documentation (https://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html, https://gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) but maybe someone knows how to do that.

**EDIT**

I generated VRT file with some sample coordinates. This is the command I used:

```sh
gdal_translate -gcp 100 100 200 200 -gcp 200 200 300 300 -gcp 500 500 600 600 -of VRT original.tif original.vrt
```

And this is the output file:

```xml
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="16285" rasterYSize="8251">
  <Metadata>
    <MDI key="TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT">1 (unitless)</MDI>
    <MDI key="TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION">1</MDI>
    <MDI key="TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION">1</MDI>
  </Metadata>
  <Metadata domain="IMAGE_STRUCTURE">
    <MDI key="INTERLEAVE">BAND</MDI>
  </Metadata>
  <GCPList>
    <GCP Id="" Pixel="100.0000" Line="100.0000" X="2.000000000000E+02" Y="2.000000000000E+02" />
    <GCP Id="" Pixel="200.0000" Line="200.0000" X="3.000000000000E+02" Y="3.000000000000E+02" />
    <GCP Id="" Pixel="500.0000" Line="500.0000" X="6.000000000000E+02" Y="6.000000000000E+02" />
  </GCPList>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">
    <Metadata domain="IMAGE_STRUCTURE">
      <MDI key="NBITS">1</MDI>
    </Metadata>
    <Metadata>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM">1</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MEAN">0.074397271632616</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MINIMUM">0</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_STDDEV">0.26241630590769</MDI>
    </Metadata>
    <ColorInterp>Palette</ColorInterp>
    <ColorTable>
      <Entry c1="255" c2="255" c3="255" c4="255" />
      <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255" />
    </ColorTable>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">original.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="16285" RasterYSize="8251" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="16285" BlockYSize="4" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="16285" ySize="8251" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="16285" ySize="8251" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

Now, I tried to use this as the input for warping:

```py
import gdal

InputImage = 'original.vrt'
OutTileName = 'warped.tif'
OutTile = gdal.Warp(OutTileName, InputImage, options=gdal.WarpOptions(tps=True))
OutTile = None
```

It does not break, but as the result I get exactly the same image - like it was not warped at all. And the other thing is that the size of the input image is 16 MB, and the size of the result image is 140 MB. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign `gpc`'s specifying the shift with `gdal_translate -gcp x1 y1 x2 x2` to your file. Writing the output to a VRT file allows you to see the format, so in case you have an insane amount of `gcp`'s, it might be easier to generate the VRT from some template, instead of using the command line.

Once the `gcp`'s are assigned, you can use gdalwarp to "apply" the transformation. If the input file already has a projection specified, you might need to add the `-tps` flag in order to force the use of `gcp`'s instead of the projection. I'm not sure about that last part.

Comment: I added a sample code that I used to generate the VRT file and to warp the image using this file, but it's not working as expected.

Comment: You specified a constant shift of +100 for both x,y. That won't change the image (pixels), only the coordinates (the location). If you have a constant shift, it's probably better to simply change the geotransform of the image and leave the actual data alone.

Comment: Those are just simple data, I used more complex shift vectors (562 of them) and the result was the same. I am just wondering, I am processing map tiles but the operation I am trying to perform is not really related to the GIS at all. I am only trying to warp the image using given shift vectors and I need to do that based on pixels, not the real world units. Is GDAL a good tool to do such transformations? I tried to find the way to do it with opencv or pillow but I didn't.

Comment: Depending on the projection of the file (or lack thereof), it might be the format of the gcp coordinates? It should be `-gcp pixel line easting northing elevation`. For a geotransform of `[0,1,0,0,0,1]` its basically from pixels to pixels, otherwise you might need to translate the in or output coordinates from map to pixel, or vice versa.